# throttle cpu usage of a web request

Tags: c#, performance, iis-7

I have a website where every 20 minutes or so a very expensive page is hit which pegs the cpu at 100% and all my users suffer. The responsiveness of this page is not important so I was wondering besides Thread.Sleep(), is there was a good way to stop this request from eating the cpu?

Cheers!

Comment: Why, exactly, is this page hit precisely every 20 minutes? Is it not because of user requests for that page? Why are they guaranteed to hit it approximately every 20 minutes?

Comment: How many cores do you have on the server?

Comment: What are you doing on this page anyways?

Answer (score 1):

Set the [`Thread.Priority`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.priority.aspx) to `Lowest`. The CPU utilization will still be 100%, but higher priority threads will not suffer much.

Comment: This approach is fine is you can be *sure* you are resetting the thread's priority after processing this one request--thread pool threads are returned to the pool to process future requests. Generally changing thread (or process) priority is the wrong approach (it usually masks the problem rather than fixing it, and opens up the possibility of priority inversion).